# show category id in list tree

Tags: category

[http://i.imgur.com/bEe8dD2.png](https://i.imgur.com/bEe8dD2.png)

Is there an extension that will display the category id next to the name of categories? It would be handy to know the id without having to click on various categories first.

For instance, you may have some static blocks on your site rotating products of various categories. You may want to copy that block to a new location and display different products instead. Personally I don't have any of my category ids memorized so simply being able to know what they are without having to do much digging will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty solution without a module, but should work fine even in  future updates

1. Find the file

   **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tree.php**'

   and copy it to

   **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tree.php**
2. In this new file, around line 275 you will find a function named **buildNodeName**

Replace:

```
$result = $this->escapeHtml($node->getName());
```

With:

```
$result = '[' . $node->getId() . '] ';
$result .= $this->escapeHtml($node->getName());
```

You may need to clear the cache and recompile.